# HaProxy redirect to internal URL

Tags: redirect, haproxy, 301-redirect, html

I have a configuration with two backend servers I need to redirect 301 to each server with an internal URL on HTTP. It's hard to use SSL because I can't install SSL on the Report Server in that configuration. Also, I can't use the virtual domain and shared IP to redirect traffic because there is some internal issue with Report Viewer when viewing reports.
I just need to redirect traffic to the backend server, preferably with an internal URL, but the IP will also be ok.

At the moment I know how to do it to one specific host but not to the current server.

Configuration:
Active/Passive configuration for the backend.

1. HA-Proxy version 2.0.29-0ubuntu1
2. Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
3. Keepalived v2.0.19

   ```
   frontend raporty
        bind 192.168.0..108:80
        bind 192.168.0.108:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/haproxy.pem
        default_backend reportserver
        option forwardfor

   backend reportserver
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option httpchk uri /reports
        http-check  expect status 401
        http-response set-header X-Server %s
        http-request redirect  code 301  location http://sql02.domain.local%[capture.req.uri]
        server   sql01  192.168.0.11:80 check check fall 5
        server   sql02  192.168.0.111:80 check check fall 5
        http-response set-header X-Server %s
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This was managed by using the ACL and the srv_is_up parameter.

`frontend raporty
        bind 192.168.0.108:80
        bind 192.168.0.108:443 ssl crt  /etc/ssl/certs/haproxy.pem
        http-response set-header X-Server %s
        http-response set-header Host %s
        default_backend reportserver
        option forwardfor



backend reportserver
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option httpchk uri /reports
        http-check  expect status 401
        acl asql01 srv_is_up(reportserver/sql01)
        acl asql02 srv_is_up(reportserver/sql02)
        http-request set-header Host %s
        http-response set-header Host %s
        http-request redirect  code 301 location http://sql01.domain.local%[capture.req.uri]  if asql01
        http-request redirect  code 301 location http://sql02.domain.local%[capture.req.uri]  if asql02
        server   sql01  sql01.domain.local:80 check check fall 5
        server   sql02  sql02.domain.local:80 check check fall 5
        http-response set-header X-Server %s`